# how to write a regedit key's value to move a file without opening console

Tags: batch-file, cmd, regedit

I want to write a regedit key value which moves a file from one location to some fixed location.
Following is the value for it:

```
cmd.exe /k %1 D:\MyLocation
```

But what remains after moving file is an opened console.
Please suggest a way to do this without having a console.

Comment: use `cmd /c` instead of `cmd /k`

Answer (score 0):

`cmd /K` keeps console open after execution while `cmd /C` close it

Comment: Thanks! what if i don't want console window to appear even for half a second?

Comment: maybe using `start /b cmd.exe /C ...` did not test . Remember to mark this as answer if it had helped you