# how to write a cmd command to move file and close console in one statement

Tags: cmd

Can i write a cmd command which moves file in Windows and later closes the console in one statement?
Consider my following question for full description of the scenario:
[how to write a regedit key's value to move a file without opening console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455175/how-to-write-a-regedit-keys-value-to-move-a-file-without-opening-console)

Answer (score 0):

```
move file1 file2 & exit
```

If you want to close the command line only if the `move` command was successful, use double ampersand:

```
move file1 file2 && exit
```

You can also create a batch file and run it instead of running `cmd`. The console window will close automatically (the `exit` command is not necessary)

Comment: Thanks! It works but console window also appears for a very short span when command is executed, and i don't need that.
Actually i am running this command through regedit and don't want it to show console window.

Answer (score 0):

This batch file will close after moving the file, assuming the target folder exists.

```
@move "c:\folder\file.txt" "c:\newfolder\"
```

Comment: I cannot make use of batch files. Please go through the linked question for better understanding.